# How to get favicon from url when website has no access to the internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, favicon, .net-4.6

How can I get the favicon from **ANY** webpage (webpage has for example no access to the internet) without using a 3th party application like Google S2 Converter or something else in c#/asp.net?

I am a developer of an internal Web application; we generate in one of our page a table with dynamic links to other internal websites. We don’t want to download every possible icon from the internal websites and link them in the table. Is there a way to get the icon from a page dynamically?

**example:**

```
<table>
@foreach (var mylink in Model.links) 
{
   var faviconOfPage = //Get Url of favicon > example: favicon of subpage.mycompany.com
   <tr>
       <td><a href="@(mylink.url).ToString()">@mylink.name</a></td>
       <td><img src="@faviconOfPage"></td>
   </tr>
}
</table>
```

**Note**: The requested site is internal: no access from outside!

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Favicons are traditionally located at `//host/favicon.ico`, or otherwise specified by a `<link rel="shortcut icon" />`. You can't download it when `host` is offline or otherwise inaccessible. It's really unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @CodeCaster checkout my change

Comment: That doesn't change a thing. A favicon is hosted online, in order to display it, your browser must be able to access it. Otherwise you must download it from a system that has access to the internet, and cache it somewhere accessible to your application.

Comment: @CodeCaster sure, I want the favicon of intranet.mycompany.com. I have access to the page because I am in the internal network. But Google has no access to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A favicon can be supplied through two ways: convention (located at `/favicon.ico` at the root of the site) or through the `<link rel="shortcut icon" />` element.

Because the latter can be the case for every page, you need to request and parse every page to see whether that `<link>` element is present, and if so, download the file specified by the `href` attribute. If not, you can download the `/favicon.ico` from the host.

Since you need to do this per page, and since it can differ per request, you're going to need some caching. You can't request and parse N pages for every page of your web application containing N links, because that would make your application horribly slow.

So create some kind of background job that processes your links, downloads their favicons and stores them in a way so that you can associate icons with links.

Comment: I think the better way is to download the favicon and link them in the surcecode :) Because I dont want to cache some icons

Comment: No, that's not the better way, because as I said, that's going to make your page horribly slow. If a page contains 10 links, you'll need to download and parse 10 HTML documents before you can start rendering your page. _"I don't want to"_ is not a valid complaint to _"You need to"_.

Comment: I mean: I download manully the images and link them in the page